# how to exclude test dependences in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

first, I have a project like this:

```
project-a
   src
      main
          java
              A.java
      test
          java
              ATest.java
```

then, I have another project like this:

```
project-b
   src
      main
          java
              B.java
      test
          java
              BTest.java
```

the build.gradle configuration, project-b dependence project-a

```
dependencies{
    compile project(":project-a")
}
```

the question is BTest.java can access ATest.java, how to avoid this?

-------------------show more detail---------------
[image]

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'test-dependence'

include 'project-a', 'project-b'
```

project-b/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile project(":project-a")
   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: I maybe write BTest.java in project-a, and then conflict, so do not want the dependence

Comment: In my testing, `BTest.java` cannot access `ATest.java` with a typical project dependency. Are you sure that you are seeing this? If so, can you share more about your Gradle files?

Comment: @MichaelEaster i have add the demo detail

Comment: Are you sure you're launching the tests with gradle, and not with the IDE (bypassing gradle?). What happens when you execute `./gradlew project-b:test`?

Comment: @JBNizet As you said, ATest.class not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's a bit of an impedence mismatch between Gradle modules and IntelliJ modules since Gradle allows multiple classpaths (configurations) in a module and IntelliJ has a single classpath per module.

Basically IntelliJ will allow BTest.java to access ATest.java but if you built from command line, Gradle won't allow it.

Try the following in intellij Gradle Settings.

```
Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle: check create separate modules per source set
```

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018567/why-my-gradle-projects-creates-separated-modules-for-main-and-test-in-intellij-I)