# Intellij + Gradle: Why is my main and test folders marked as a project module?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

My IntelliJ Gradle project shows some unexpected behavior. As can be seen from the picture, this module (itself a submodule in a multi-module build) shows the src/main and src/test folders as modules (the little blue square denotes a module).

[image]

Nothing in any of the build.gradle files anywhere mentions the src, or main, or test folders.

The idea plugin is being used.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Actually they are treated as modules. Please see "Project Structure | Modules"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my gradle projects creates separated modules for main and test in Intellij Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018567/why-my-gradle-projects-creates-separated-modules-for-main-and-test-in-intellij-i)